# Bootstrap.min extremely slow in chrome while firefox runs fine

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, lag

Does anyone know why this is happening?

This occurs the section where the responsive video is embedded in the webpage.

Firefox runs fine, but chrome lags where that spot is crossed.

How to mitigate this issue? I am using instead.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: it is unclear what your problem is an what you are asking

Comment: Bootstrap loads slow when using chrome. How is this unclear?

Comment: because you said nothing about "loading slow" in the original post. Have you checked the network tab in chome dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, IE / FF works fast while chrome was slow.
I used bootstrap rtl version,

issue solved when i removed the direction: rtl property from the html tag.